# Is $AB$ a covariance matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, covariance

Suppose we have two covariance matrices $A$ and $B$. They satisfy the condition $AB=BA$. Is $AB$ a covariance matrix?

My answers:

We can easily check that $(AB)'=B'A'=BA$, then $AB$ is symmetric. But I have no idea how to check it is positive semi-definite. I can't come up with an example showing it isn't a covariance matrix, either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $AB=BA$, then $A$ and $B$ can be simultaneously diagonalized by some matrix $U$. Hence it follows
\begin{align}
AB = UD_1U^{-1}UD_2U^{-1} = UD_1D_2U^{-1}.
\end{align}
Thus, the eigenvalues of $AB$ are product of eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$. Thus, it follows $AB$ is also positive semi-definite since the eigenvalues are nonnegative.

Comment: Product of the corresponding eigenvalues.

Comment: @Batman Ops. I have corrected the statement. Thanks.

Comment: @JackyChong, I can't understand why "Since AB=BA, then A and B can be simultaneously diagonalized by some matrix U". Could you elaborate it a little more in detail? Thanks again!

Comment: $AB=(U_A \Lambda_A U_A^{-1}) (U_B \Lambda_B U_B^{-1}) =  (U_B \Lambda_B U_B^{-1})  (U_A \Lambda_A U_A^{-1}) = BA$, I can't figure out what is the $U$ as mentioned in the answer, thanks again!

Comment: @Pandaaaaaaa Commuting matrices have the same eigenbasis.

Comment: @JackyChongThanks Jack.